# Two sets of indentical tables with joins using indexes in MySQL; one requires full-table scan

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-table-scan

Im getting very confused with indexes in MySQL.

I have two tables:  TableA1 and TableA2.

I created indexes on these for the joins between them and queries run really fast.

I have another 2 tables with an identical setup e.g. TableB1 and TableB2. The only difference is that these tables have a few null values.

For some reason the same query on TableA is about 5 times faster and doesn't require a full-table scan. TableB however seems to use a full table scan and I can't work out why. Could it be the Null values that are causing this?

I notice using EXPLAIN that on the TableA setup, I get `possible keys: myindex` and also `ref: func`; however on the TableB setup I get just `possible keys: NULL` and `ref: NULL`.

I have searched around for quite a while on this, and cannot seem to find a relevant answer. Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

(Sorry, now added to the original question.)

Here is TableAOne:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableAOne` (
  `field1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `myindex` (`field1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And TableATwo:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableATwo` (
  `Field3` varchar(255) ,
  `Field4` varchar(255) ,
  `Field5` varchar(255) ,
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15522 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am joining Field3 with Field1.

The tables that get the full-table scan are identical to the above tables. The only difference is they are called TableB instead of TableA.

Cheers,
Ke

Comment: Can you post your create table scripts and perhaps also a row count from each table?

Comment: Is `NULL` a valid value to link between the B tables?  If not, exclude them using `AND b2.col IS NOT NULL` in the JOIN criteria, and `WHERE b1.col IS NOT NULL`

Comment: yep null is a valid value, there are some empty values too (not sure if this is wise!!), I would like to keep the null values and empty ones, I will post the create tables in a moment too

Comment: Two "identical" tables suggests that you aren't normalized properly.  Are we to interpret that to be literally true?  If yes, why is it necessary?

Comment: sorry added above, didnt realise i should edit my own question to add code

Comment: I have tried analyzing the tables and also optimising them. Is there anything else I can do? TableAOne and TableATwo dont have any null values, but TableBOne and TableBTwo do.

Comment: @Ke: tried to fix the formatting a bit.  You can "rollback" to a previous version if you don't like what I've done.  In addition, for the SQL you can highlight and press Ctrl-K to format using a monospace font.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: i like, thx Adam, im just learning the power of this great site :)
duffymo - by normalised, do you mean not having null/empty values?

Comment: Please re-edit your question and include the queries and the explain plan. ALso it is not very clear to me whehter you posted all table definitions involved.  Side note: i am noticing one of your tables is InnoDB and the other is MyISAM, perhaps the difference between the "identical" tables is that?

Comment: Yes, please include the queries and explain plan.

Comment: will do - i dont think its the myisam/innodb problem, because both sets of tableA and tableB are identical, its going to take me a little while to put this together, thankx for all of your helps - i really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the table and re-installed it to the db (i did change utf8 to latin1 not sure if this made a difference),however it works now, really strange! thanks v much for all the replies they certainly pushed me towards the answer cheers :)

Comment: it turned out to be the utf8 vs latin1 char set that was causing the problem.